# div section 100% height of onepage website

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, when making onepage websites, the first section is 100% height and the rest is different sizes.

How to make the first section to be 100% height of the viewport and in the same time to make it responsive?

Comment: 'make it responsive'? What do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean like foundation zurb framework, that is for all screen sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add:`html,body{height: 100%;}`to your css and the `DIV`can be set a height of 100% of viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this with JavaScript instead of trying to hack CSS to do what you want. It should be a fairly simple 3 line document ready function call.

E.g.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#top-content').height( $(window).height() );
});
```

You could also listen to browser resize events to adjust the size on change.

```
function resizeTopContent(){
    $('#top-content').height( $(window).height() )
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeTopContent();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeTopContent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the CSS "Viewport Units" properties.

```
<div id="fullSize">Body Content</div>


#fullSize {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Viewport units give you a way to scale your design depending on the size of your device. The best of it? It will adapt the resolution instantly when resizing the screen.

Values are to be given in percent (from 1 to 100).

Here are the VP Units that you can use.

- vh: VP height
- vw: VP width
- vmin: VP min height
- vmax: VP max height